# Problema com Dash no Python

Tags: python-3.x, aplicação-web

Estou tentando rodar essa aplicação no meu notebook (macbook air), e quando vou no Terminal ele não roda, porem quando roda num pc com windows não tenho nenhum problemas

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

colors = {
    'background': '#111111',
    'text': '#7FDBFF'
}

app.layout = html.Div(style={'backgroundColor': colors['background']}, children=[
    html.H1(
        children='Hello Dash',
        style={
            'textAlign': 'center',
            'color': colors['text']
        }
    ),

    html.Div(children='Dash: A web application framework for Python.', style={
        'textAlign': 'center',
        'color': colors['text']
    }),

    dcc.Graph(
        id='example-graph-2',
        figure={
            'data': [
                {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [4, 1, 2], 'type': 'bar', 'name': 'SF'},
                {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [2, 4, 5], 'type': 'bar', 'name': u'Montréal'},
            ],
            'layout': {
                'plot_bgcolor': colors['background'],
                'paper_bgcolor': colors['background'],
                'font': {
                    'color': colors['text']
                }
            }
        }
    )
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

[image: Mensagem que aparece]

Comment: Instalou a biblioteca no Mac (com `pip`)? Ou tem algum arquivo chamado `dash.py` na tua pasta?

Comment: Sim, mas tem algo estranho quando eu faço import dash ele importa mas quando eu faço import dash_core_components ele da erro e fala "Dash was not successfully imported. Make sure you don't have a file named 
'dash.py' in your current directory.
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback."